# PHP strtotime + 1 month and return 23:59

Tags: php

I can have +1 month using strtotime but how do I return that day 23:59:59?

For example now is **2013-06-19 03:28** if I were add 1 month then it will return **2013-07-19 03:28** but I need **2013-07-19 23:59**.

Comment: Show the code. It may help.

Comment: Anybody researching techniques to find the end of a day, week, month or year, like I was?  I've just realised, counter-intuitively, at least for programming purposes, the start of the day after that, is probably what I actually need.  Is 23:59 the end of a day?  No.  There's a whole minute left to go.  How about 23:59:59?  Obviously, there's still a second there.  OK, 23:59:59.999, then?  Good enough, probably, but it's not as straight-forward as finding midnight of the subsequent day, that's when the day before it is truly over. e.g. `strtotime('midnight first day of next month')` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime("+1 month"));
```

Answer (score 3):

While orangepill's answer *is* useful, I think this is more clear:

```
<?php

// You time as Unix timestamp
$now = strtotime('2013-06-19 03:28');

$d = new DateTime();

// Whenever doing date calculations, timezone is important. Set it to "UTC" if you don't care.
$d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit'));

// Initialize date ( - but remember, DateTime can take many other forms of date input)
$d->setTimeStamp($now);

// Increase date by 1 month.
$d->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));

// Overwrite the "clock" part of the date
$d->setTime(23, 59, 59);

// Display the result:
var_dump($d);
```